# After I upgraded to ubuntu 14.04.3, I couldn't boot to my windows systems

Tags: dual-boot

I have 2 Sata 1TB drives. I setup originally with win7SP1 and Ubuntu 14.04 on the Toshiba Drive and WinXPSP3 on the WD drive.

Everything worked beautifully... Then I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04.3, and now I can only boot into linux... As a matter of fact, Files doesn't even show the Toshiba Drive (which I used to see on the desktop above the trash icon) and it complains that its partition only has 364 MB - egad!

I did a boot-repair yesterday, got an [18 page text document](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/13145212/).  Obviously, to me, everything seems to be present, yet grub or grub2 doesn't create the correct boot selection or coding.

Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Run this in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

this command will scan for boot able operating systems and add them to the boot menu

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer did help you, please don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)